# Python Script trying to generate a YAML file (Containerlab topology file) as output but getting the wrong format

Tags: python-3.x, automation, yaml, pyyaml, ruamel.yaml

I am currently working on a Python file that aims to generate a "custom" containerlab topolgy file - yaml format - but I am getting a different output than expected and I am struggling big time to fix it.

Here is an example of aimple Lab topology file Im trying to generate using the mentioned python script:

```yaml
name: Test

topology:
  nodes:
    device1:
      kind: device_type
      image: image
    device2:
      kind: device_type
      image: image
    device3:
      kind: device_type
      image: image
  links:
    - endpoints: ["device1:eth1", "device2:eth1"]
    - endpoints: ["device2:eth2", "device3:eth2"]
```

Instead, I am getting this:

```yaml
- name: Test
- topology:
  - nodes:
    - device1:
        kind: device_type
        image: image
    - device2:
        kind: device_type
        image: image
    - device3:
        kind: device_type
        image: image
  links:
  - endpoints:
    - device1:eth1
    - device2:eth1
  - endpoints:
    - device2:eth2
    - device3:eth2
```

This is the Python script I have so far:

```py
import ruamel.yaml as yaml

# Create an ordered dictionary representing the lab name
lab_name = yaml.comments.CommentedMap()
lab_name['name'] = yaml.comments.CommentedSeq()

# Create an ordered dictionary representing the topology
topology_dict = yaml.comments.CommentedMap()
topology_dict['topology'] = yaml.comments.CommentedSeq()
topo_dict = yaml.comments.CommentedMap()
topo_dict['nodes'] = yaml.comments.CommentedSeq()
topo_dict['links'] = yaml.comments.CommentedSeq()

# Define the number of nodes
num_nodes = int(input("Enter the number of nodes: "))

# Define the LAB name
# Creating a Function that Verifies Lab valid name or not
def is_valid_lab_name(name):
    if name is None:
        return False
    elif " " in name:
        return False
    elif not all(char.isalnum() or char == "_" for char in name):
        return False
    return True

# Prompt users for input until valid name is provided

while True:
    lab_name_input = input("Enter the Lab Topology name (No Spaces, only '_' allowed): ")
    if is_valid_lab_name(lab_name_input):
        lab_name = {"name":str(f"{lab_name_input}")}
        break
    else:
        print("Invalid name. Please try again.")


# Generate nodes and links
for i in range(1, num_nodes + 1):
    node_name = str(f"ceos{i}")
    node = {
        node_name: {
        "kind": "ceos",
        "image": "device/image"
        }
    }
    topo_dict['nodes'].append(node)

    if i > 1:
        link = {
            "endpoints": str([f"{node_name}:eth1", f"ceos{i-1}:eth1"]),
        }
        topo_dict['links'].append(link)


# Integrating Nodes List Dictionary into Main Topology Dictionary
topology_dict = {'topology': [{'nodes': topo_dict['nodes']}]}


# Loop through LINKS dictionary and refactor links to CLAB format
for item in topo_dict['links']:
    if 'endpoints' in item:
        value = item['endpoints']
        if isinstance(value, str):
            # Remove single quotes and replace square brackets with lists
            updated_value = eval(value.replace("'", '"'))
            
            # Update the original dictionary with the modified value
            item['endpoints'] = updated_value


# Integrating Nodes List Dictionary into Main Topology Dictionary
topology_dict['links'] = list(topo_dict['links'])


# Append both Dictionaries, Name and Topology into the same YAML file
lab_file = [lab_name, topology_dict]


# Create a YAML file
with open("dynamic_topology.yaml", "w") as yaml_file:
    yaml.dump(lab_file, yaml_file, Dumper=yaml.RoundTripDumper, default_flow_style=False)


print("--------------------------------------------")
print("Dynamic topology file created successfully")
print("--------------------------------------------")
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I merge two dictionaries in a single expression in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38987/how-do-i-merge-two-dictionaries-in-a-single-expression-in-python)

Comment: The line `lab_file = [lab_name, topology_dict]` creates a **list** from two dictionaries. Exactly that list is represented by the YAML file. If you want to combine dictionaries into the single **dictionary**, then use `lab_file = lab_name | topology_dict` or any other way for that purpose.

Comment: Thank you for your quick responses, this was helpful! The pipe "|" helped with the serialization better. And now this is what it comes back:

```yaml
name: Test
topology:
- nodes:
  - ceos1:
      kind: ceos
      image: device/image
  - ceos2:
      kind: ceos
      image: device/image
  - ceos3:
      kind: ceos
      image: device/image
links:
- endpoints:
  - ceos2:eth1
  - ceos1:eth1
- endpoints:
  - ceos3:eth1
  - ceos2:eth1
```
I think the recipient library, im trying to send this output to, won't accept the "-" on nodes and each device name. I will keep testing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're serializing a list, not a dictionary...so you're get a YAML document that represents a list:

```
lab_file = [lab_name, topology_dict]
```

If you want a YAML dictionary as output, you need to provide a dictionary to `yaml.dump`. Something like:

```
topology_dict.update(lab_name)
with open("dynamic_topology.yaml", "w") as yaml_file:
    yaml.dump(topology_dict, yaml_file, Dumper=yaml.RoundTripDumper, default_flow_style=False)
```

---

Also, note that this:

```
  links:
  - endpoints:
    - device1:eth1
    - device2:eth1
  - endpoints:
    - device2:eth2
    - device3:eth2
```

And this:

```
  links:
    - endpoints: ["device1:eth1", "device2:eth1"]
    - endpoints: ["device2:eth2", "device3:eth2"]
```

Are alternate representations of identical data structures.

Comment: Thank you! This was definitely helpful. I was able to serialize data into dictionaries with the suggestions above. Now noticed that the "links" dictionary does not respect indentation now as its one more object within the Topology list (nods and links dictionaries). Respectively, is there a way to further remove the "-" of the "nodes" and each node inside it?

Comment: You shouldn't think in terms of removing characters: you need to think about the data structures you're looking to represent. In this case, the difference is serializing a dictionary vs. serializing a list.

Comment: Thank you! This is helpful, I did test the suggested outputs and it looks way better!